# Indented import statement causes parsing error in stylish-haskell

Tags: haskell, formatting, format, indentation

When trying to format the following test programme `Char.hs`, stylish-haskell reports a parsing error:

```hs
module Char (caesarCipher, caesarDecipher)
    where

    import Data.Char (ord, chr)

    caesarCipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
    caesarCipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (+ shift) $ map (ord) msg

    caesarDecipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
    caesarDecipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (subtract shift) $ map (ord) msg
```

Part of the verbose log by stylish-haskell:

```
$ stylish-haskell -v Char.hs          
...
Stylish Haskell will work basing on LANGUAGE pragmas in source files.
Enabled Cases step
Enabled Imports (ghc-lib-parser) step
Enabled LanguagePragmas step
Enabled TrailingWhitespace step
Extra language extensions: []
Char.hs: <string>:6:5: error: parse error on input `caesarCipher'
```

Where stylish-haskell has not been configured with any config files as reflected in the folded part of the verbose report; `Char.hs` is a standalone non-project file, and nothing did GHC complain throughout compilation:

```
$ ghc Char.hs   
[1 of 1] Compiling Char             ( Char.hs, Char.o )
```

---

After some testing, the problem seems to be about the import statement, in which:

- Stylish-haskell works fine after removing all the indents:

  ```hs
  module Char (caesarCipher, caesarDecipher)
  where

  import Data.Char (ord, chr)

  caesarCipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
  caesarCipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (+ shift) $ map (ord) msg

  caesarDecipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
  caesarDecipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (subtract shift) $ map (ord) msg
  ```
- Stylish-haskell also works when only removing the import statement, even though GHC complains about this:

  ```hs
  module Char (caesarCipher, caesarDecipher)
  where

      -- import Data.Char (chr, ord)

      caesarCipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
      caesarCipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (+ shift) $ map (ord) msg

      caesarDecipher :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
      caesarDecipher shift msg = map (chr) $ map (subtract shift) $ map (ord) msg
  ```

Where the only thing making stylish-haskell unhappy seems to be the *indented import statement*. Just to clarify, I know import statements must be on the same indentation level as the others and I did not violate that in any situation; I've always been using the space character instead of tabs and I never mix them in any instances.

---

Therefore, my questions are:

- Is it syntactically accepted to indent the whole module body an extra level forward? I have not seen many code examples doing this, but neither some articles saying "don't do this"
- If yes, then what causes stylish-haskell not to work while the code is syntactically correct?
- If no, then why GHC says nothing about it?
- Is it possible to keep the indent while making stylish-haskell working on it?

To whom may be interested in, I'm using GHC 8.10.7 and stylish-haskell 0.14.1.0. Just shout to me if you need more info.

Comment: You should limit your question to one question if possible, but answers are:

1) You cannot indent the contents of a module like you're trying to.
2) see 1
3) I would be very surprised if GHC didn't complain, as that isn't a valid Haskell file.
4) no, because top level definitions in Haskell files _must_ shave no indentation.

Comment: @Axman6 indenting everything after the `module ... where` is allowed. It seems this is a bug in stylish-haskell.

Comment: This has blown my mind, I've been using Haskell for well over a decade and never seen this (please don't do it even if it is allowed, it'll confuse the hell out of every other Haskell developer, and makes finding top level definitions harder)

Comment: 1) This is indeed just a bug in stylish haskell... Just report this to the stylish haskell people, or if you're feeling a little more handsy, start looking into the source code and see if you can find the issue yourself 2) it's allowed to indent modules, but I'd strongly recommend against it. Since _everything_ is in a module, you're just adding whitespace to _all_ lines for no reason.

Comment: @Cubic I indent the module body as in accordance to indenting the where part in a function... Thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation rules of Haskell are formally specified in [section 10.3 of the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3) and a simplified version is given in [section 2.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7).

My understanding is the following (in the context of your programs).

1. The body of your program is a list of imports and top level declarations.
2. When using the layout rule all of these must have the same indentation.
3. The level of indentation is determined by the first declaration after the `where` from module.

So based on this all of the above programs should be correct. Though with a rather unconventional indentation.

Notes:

1. The body is everything that comes after `module ...... where`
2. The alternative to using the layout rule is to manually add braces `{`, `}` and semicolons `;` to separate declarations, similar to how this is done in languages like C. This gives you a 'layout-insensitive program'
3. The actual definition of the Haskell syntax uses braces and semi-colons. The specification describes how the layout of your file can be translated into a layout-insensitive. See again [1](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3) for the complete description of the algorithm and the following section 10.5 for the actual Haskell syntax definition.